# Find duplicate values in a field results in multiple rows of the same values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count

Suppose this [table](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=340891ff5f51553f94048704506f1a01)

I want to get all `CODE`s where `SIZEPOS` has the same value more than once...

So for the product

```
('194342-01', 10510, 5),
('194342-01', 10510, 7),
('194342-01', 10510, 9),
('194342-01', 10510, 11),
('194342-01', 10510, 13),
('194342-01', 10510, 15),
('194342-01', 10510, 5),
('194342-01', 10510, 19),
```

I would like to get `'194342-01', 10510, 5` as `SIZEPOS` 5 appears twice. I achieved it with the following query

```
SELECT CODE, ITEID, COUNT(SIZEPOS) AS CNT
FROM @SUBSTITUTE
GROUP BY CODE, ITEID, SIZEPOS
HAVING COUNT(SIZEPOS) > 1;
```

but for some reason some of the returned rows appear twice, or even three times... What am I missing here?

Comment: You aren't getting any duplicate rows returned - you're just not showing the `SIZEPOS` column in your resultset, but you specifically said you want to keep distinct `SIZEPOS` values. Add it to your resultset and you'll see that every row is unique. Which is kinda obvious given you are grouping by every column. Maybe you need to remove a column from your group-by? Or maybe the results are perfect as they are.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out later, that some rows had duplicate values for multiple values... Hence they were displayed each time for any different value that appeared more than once...

In that case of course I needed DISTINCT in my query, and that's what I ended up doing!

Thanks @DaleK for being so helpful and kind at the same time!

Comment: You are right, sorry for that! I can accept my own answer though in 20 hours, as I was informed by the system!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using DISTINCT in my main query to avoid rows appearing more than once. So the query became like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CODE, ITEID, COUNT(SIZEPOS) AS CNT
FROM @SUBSTITUTE
GROUP BY CODE, ITEID, SIZEPOS
HAVING COUNT(SIZEPOS) > 1;
```

The rows that were appearing more than once, were rows that had different values with duplicates, so each row corresponded to every different duplicate value! This was easy but took me some time to figure out!

Comment: Your question/answer doesn't actually make sense though. You specify you want to combine rows where `SIZEPOS` has the same value more than once, but you are combining all values of `SIZEPOS` and just getting distinct results for `CODE, ITEID` - in which case just remove `SIZEPOS` from the `group by` clause?

Comment: I didn't need the `SIZEPOS` info. To be specific the fiddle I provided is an oversimplified case that I realized is happening in a clietn's DB. He mistakenly defined duplicate sizes for the same product. Ie, <SKU1>, <COLOR1>, <SIZE1>, <SKU2>, <COLOR2>, <SIZE2>, <SKU3>, <COLOR3>, <SIZE1>. So all I needed was a way to detect those product ID, and exclude them from a further processing... In the final query I didn't even use `ITEID`, nor `COUNT(SIZEPOS)`. Just the 'DISTINCT CODE's

Comment: Either way, its seriously not clear from the question. In future try for a [MRE] where you show the exact desired results you want for you provided sample data.